# What are the differences between display:box and display:flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

It's my understanding that the CSS Flexible Box Layout module is being rewritten and that `display:box` is being deprecated in favor of `display:flexbox`.

Is `display:flexbox` currently supported in any browser (release, beta, or nightly)? Does anyone know where I can find some information as to what's new in flexbox, what the differences are between it and the old module, and/or why the old module was rewritten?

Comment: [Can I use?](http://caniuse.com/flexbox)

Comment: No, caniuse.com refers to the old implementation, not the new one.

Comment: @Philip Does it?  Seems to be based on the new working draft - http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/ (with browser prefixes...)

Comment: No, it's not. Look at the examples, they all use `display:box`.

Comment: Ah, I stand corrected :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like at this time good information is not available. I will update this post if and when I find good information.

**Update:** (2/20/2012) [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) now shows the browser support for both the new and old versions of the Flexible Box Layout Module

**Update:** (8/7/2012) Chris Coyer has put together a nice article about how to tell the difference between the new and old syntax. http://css-tricks.com/old-flexbox-and-new-flexbox/

Comment: Could you quote or summarize the article here? Helps people who are just stopping by from searches and are lazy to click more links. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

[Compatibility table for flexbox support](http://caniuse.com/flexbox)

In short: IE10+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, iOS and Android.

Comment: This is for `display:box`, not `display:flexbox`, if you look at the examples, they all use `display:box`. Also, the writing of the new spec started in 2011, so there's no way FF2 had support for it.

Comment: No, `box-flex` is a property you can use on children of elements who are set to `display:box`.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention, the official values for "display" in the Flexbox spec are "flexbox" and "inline-flexbox", as of the March 2011 Working Draft. The "box" value was mentioned in the first Working Draft (July 2009) and is the one that has most widespread support at the moment, but should now be replaced by "flexbox".