# Why does Firefox compute an element's width as 0 when it is set to 100% if an ancestor of the element has display: box?

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

It seems that in Firefox, if I have div `A` with fixed width/height and it has a child div `B` with width and height set to 100%, then `B` will have a computed width of 0 (and hence not be displayed) if `A` or any other ancestor of `B` has `display: box` (or the appropriate vendor-prefixed version) set.

Example HTML:

```
<div id="a">
  <div id="b"></div>
</div>
```

Example CSS:

```
#a {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
}
#b {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

In firefox, a green box will be shown, but in Chrome, a red one shows.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7QpX/25/) for viewing this example. [Here is another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7QpX/26/) with another layer of nested divs that shows that this occurs even if it is not the direct parent of the element in question which has `display: box`.

I would like the `width: 100%` declaration on B to force it to be the same size as the parent (i.e. the behavior in Chrome). Why is the width computed to be 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `box-flex: 1.0;` (defaults to `0.0`) for `#b` in your example has the desired effect: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upWB8/).

- [Flexible Box, W3C Working Draft, 23 July 2009](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-css3-flexbox-20090723/) supported by Firefox
- [Flexible Box, W3C Working Draft, 29 November 2011](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) supported by Chrome
- [Can I use Flexbox?](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)
- Possibly relevant question: [What are the differences between display:box and display:flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796757/what-are-the-differences-between-displaybox-and-displayflexbox)

Comment: Thanks! This does the trick. In my application (but not the minimal examples in the fiddles), just adding `display: box` (or the prefixed equivalents) to the inner div made it work.

Answer (score 0):

The height isn't computed as zero: it's the width. Try putting some content into B (say `&nbsp;&nbsp;`).

`display:box` has the desired effect. Using `-moz-box` alters the box model. You obviously don't want the CSS3 box model, so you shouldn't use `-moz-box`.

Comment: display: -moz-box; is definitely the problem. Remove that line your example will work.

Comment: Jeff: my layout is done with flexboxes. That's the point of the post: I want to know why the inner div doesn't expand to fill the parent if one of the ancestors has `display: box`. (`display: -moz-box` is the vendor-prefixed version of `display: box`.)

Comment: Hmm, interesting -- this is correct. I must have produced a faulty minimal example (on my actual page, it is the height that is 0, not the width).

Comment: `display:box` and `display:-moz-box` are **not** synonymous and behave differently in Mozilla browsers (which I why there is a -moz version, I suppose). You want the behaviour of `display:box`.

Comment: Andrew -- I do want the CSS3 box model; that's the source of my issues. On my real page, my layout is done with flexboxes.

Comment: In that case I suggest creating an example which demonstrates the issue!

Comment: Andrew: at least according to [this page](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/) `display: box` is how you specify the flexible box model, and `-moz-box`/`-webkit-box` are the corresponding vendor-prefixed versions. Obviously if you get rid of `display: -moz-box` and add in `display: box` it "works", but that is because firefox ignores `display: box` completely.

Comment: http://blog.isotoma.com/2010/08/css3-flexbox/ notes that *Observant viewer [sic] will have noticed that Firefox (3.6.8) ignores the width and height setting on the child boxes, whilst Webkit respects it but overflows the content.* So it looks like CSS3 isn't quite there yet (or it's a bug which might be fixed, depending on your point of view).

Comment: @AndrewLeach The width is indeed the problem (and the difference is probably just that `box-orient` is `vertical` or `horizontal` on the ancestor flexbox). I've updated the post title, text, and examples to correctly identify this.