# What's the difference between display:box and display:flexbox in css3

Tags: css, flexbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the differences between display:box and display:flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796757/what-are-the-differences-between-displaybox-and-displayflexbox)

I have read a css3 `flex-box` [demo](http://jsbin.com/upumiw/edit#html,live) here,the parent element's style is :

```
  .flexbox {
    display: -webkit-flexbox;    
    -webkit-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-flex-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background: orange;
  }
```

Once I change the `display: -webkit-flexbox;` to `display: -webkit-box;`, the page layout have changed.

Buy I read some tutorial about the `-webkit-flexbox` and `-webkit-box` just is the same syntax.Is that true? Are there some differences between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [source](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/19/css3-flexible-box-layout-explained/) the specs have changed:

The Working Draft has undergone changes to much of the syntax used in the flexbox model. For example:

```
display: box;
```

This will become:

```
display: flexbox;
```

Both versions of the syntax work (at least in chrome). The reason why the layout looks different if you change the `display` style is because you have to change `-webkit-flex-pack: center;` to `-webkit-box-pack: center;` when you use `display: -webkit-box;`

So this is equivalent to your css style from above and should produce the same layout:

```
.flexbox {
    display: -webkit-box;    
    -webkit-flex-box: center;
    -webkit-flex-box: center;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background: orange;
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, they nearly rewrote the whole thing. It was a huge mess, but fortunately it's gotten better since the rewrite.